# Why does the graph look like that?

Tags: calculus

I am studying about Specific Energy in open channel hydraulic from a book.

The equation for that is: $E_s=y+\cfrac{\alpha q^2}{2gy^2}$ where $q$ and $\alpha$ are constant. therefore we have:

$$\left(E_s-y\right)y^2=\cfrac{\alpha q^2}{2g}=constant$$
Or:
$$\left(E_s-y\right)=constant/y^2$$
If we only consider positive solutions of $y$
Then according to the book the graph of that is :

[image]

But I don't understand why the graph is look like that. for example why there is it has two asymptotes and why for every $E_s$ we have two values of $y$ corresponding to it?

Comment: Are you sure there are asymptotes? $\left(E_s-y\right)y^2=constant$ is a 3rd degree polynomial in the variable $E_s$.

Comment: Clearly when $y$ is very large $y-E_s$ has to be very very small to ensure $(E_s-y)y^2=k$. I would sketch in turn (i) $YX=c$ (ii) $Y^2X=c$ (iii) $y^2(y-x)=c$ (the last step squeezes the 1st quadrant into the 1st octant, just like in your picture).

Comment: @BernardMassé yes. and it only considered for positive values of $y$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: very good idea. But I don't understand why the last step squeeze the graph to first octant.

Comment: The change of variables $Y=y, X=x-y$ does that doesn't it?  [Or something of the sort, it's linear after all : maybe I have got it backwards, but the idea is right.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E_s=\frac{k+y^3}{y^2}$$
$$E_s=y+\frac{k}{y^2}$$
As $y\to 0^+$ we have $E_s\to +\infty$, horizontal asymptote $y=0$.

As $y\to+\infty$ we have $E_s\to y$, slant asymptote $y=E_s$.

Furthermore $y=E_s-\frac{k}{y^2}$ ($y>0$) shows that the graph is always under the first quadrant bisector $y=E_s$.